# jQuery:passing the value of the left propriety as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to understand how this code is working:
I'm confused what is the role of the **index** parameter and how we pass the value of the left propriety as **oldValue**

```
 box.css({
        left: function(index ,oldValue) {
            return myDemoFunction(oldValue, param1,param2);
        }
```

Comment: that is well documented ;) https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function

Comment: @johnSmith my bad i think i should start using official documentation for learning